# Unity 3d Camera not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my cameras in Unity... I have a Player-Prefab, which I add to the scene programmatically. At the moment I am adding two Player-Objects to the scene, one `isHumanControlled` and one is controlled by the computer.

If the player is not human controlled, I am deactivating scripts for walking and turning around with the mouse **and** I am disabling the camera, which is part of the prefab.

If the Player is human controlled, I am enabling the corresponding camera. Both `Debug.Log(...);` values are `true`, but in the scene I get the following error:

**Display 1 - No cameras rendering**

Can anyone see, what I am doing wrong? While in-game, the camera stays active and enabled and the `Target Display` is set to `Display 1`.

Greetings

ShanBox

```
if (!_gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            _gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (!_camera.gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            _camera.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (!_isHumanControlled)
        {
            _gameObject.GetComponent<FPSWalkerEnhanced>().enabled = false;
            _gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerPerspective>().enabled = false;
            _camera.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _gameObject.GetComponent<FPSWalkerEnhanced>().enabled = true;
            _gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerPerspective>().enabled = true;
            _camera.enabled = true;
        }
        Debug.Log("is camera active ? " + _camera.gameObject.activeSelf);
        Debug.Log("is camera enabled ? " + _camera.enabled);
```

Comment: where is the script attached?

Comment: The script is attached to the player prefab. The script gets called from the GameControllerScript, which is attached to an empty GameObject in my scene and has references to all relevant GameObjects and Scripts

Comment: I don't think the code you posted runs: a disabled game object means that all of its children and all of its children's components don't update (or at least, not in the normal sense). That means that scripts don't execute, ergo your code doesn't run and the camera does not get disabled.

Comment: The code is running ;-) My Script gets executed which was proven through the Logs I made. Nevertheless, I was able to solve this problem. I removed the Camera from the Player-Prefab, made the Camera itself a prefab and added the Camera-Prefab programmatically to the Player instance.